# Laravel 5.3 - How to encrypt .env

Tags: php, environment-variables, laravel-5.3

How to encrypt .env in laravel 5.3?

I have this problem in an application. I need to encrypt .env information to upload the application to production

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use real environment variables in production, instead of simulating them via code?

Comment: The client wants the password information to be encrypted

Comment: May be of help https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/encrypt-environment-variables

Comment: This may also be of help, you didn't google this at all did you! https://packagist.org/packages/faustbrian/laravel-environment

Answer (score 1):

### Encrypting Environment Files

Unencrypted environment files should never be stored in source control. However, Laravel allows you to encrypt your environment files so that they may safely be added to source control with the rest of your application.

### Encryption

To encrypt an environment file, you may use the `env:encrypt` command:

> `php artisan env:encrypt`

Running the `env:encrypt` command will encrypt your `.env` file and place the encrypted contents in an `.env.encrypted` file. The decryption key is presented in the output of the command and should be stored in a secure password manager. If you would like to provide your own encryption key you may use the `--key` option when invoking the command:

> `php artisan env:encrypt --key=3UVsEgGVK36XN82KKeyLFMhvosbZN1aF`

The length of the key provided should match the key length required by the encryption cipher being used. By default, Laravel will use the `AES-256-CBC` cipher which requires a 32 character key. You are free to use any cipher supported by Laravel's encrypter by passing the `--cipher` option when invoking the command.

If your application has multiple environment files, such as .env and `.env.staging`, you may specify the environment file that should be encrypted by providing the environment name via the `--env` option:

> `php artisan env:encrypt --env=staging`

### Decryption

To decrypt an environment file, you may use the `env:decrypt` command. This command requires a decryption key, which Laravel will retrieve from the `LARAVEL_ENV_ENCRYPTION_KEY` environment variable:

> `php artisan env:decrypt`

Or, the key may be provided directly to the command via the `--key` option:

> `php artisan env:decrypt --key=3UVsEgGVK36XN82KKeyLFMhvosbZN1aF`

When the `env:decrypt` command is invoked, Laravel will decrypt the contents of the `.env.encrypted` file and place the decrypted contents in the `.env` file.

The `--cipher` option may be provided to the env:decrypt command in order to use a custom encryption cipher:

> `php artisan env:decrypt --key=qUWuNRdfuImXcKxZ --cipher=AES-128-CBC`

If your application has multiple environment files, such as .env and `.env.staging`, you may specify the environment file that should be decrypted by providing the environment name via the `--env` option:

> `php artisan env:decrypt --env=staging`

In order to overwrite an existing environment file, you may provide the `--force` option to the `env:decrypt` command:

> `php artisan env:decrypt --force`

source: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/configuration#encrypting-environment-files